# 3 column fixed width layout, fixed sides and header, scrollable center content..?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm having problems with a layout design which should be easy. I actually have it working except that my menu (left sidebar) css transitions get messed up the way I'm doing it.

I want a 3 column fixed layout with a header and a footer, the whole content centered. My left and right divs are both 220px wide, 100% high and are not scrollable (so the menu is always there). The middle content div is 830px wide and is scrollable. Any monitor size beyond 1270px  will just add space to the left and right body.

Currently, I'm doing it by positioning the content as follows:

```
header{
position:fixed;
left:50%;
margin-left:-(width/2)px;
}

left{
position:fixed;
left:50%;
margin-left:-635px; <--(center width/2) - left width)
}

center{
position:relative;
left:50%;
margin-left:-415; <--center width/2
}

right{
position:fixed;
left:50%;
margin-left:415px;
}
```

Again, this works except is causes my css transitions to hang in Chrome. The problem is the left/margin left method for setting the content, because if I set left using say left:50px; then all is well.

I've tried to float:left everything, but that causes the whole page to scroll which I don't want. Any clue how to stick that left bar to the left of the center div another way?